# What is the purpose of END_FINALLY bytecode in older Python versions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode, cpython

Consider the following code:

```py
try:
    helloworld()
except:
    failure()
```

and its disassembly (this is in Python 2.7):

```
  1           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            11 (to 14)

  2           3 LOAD_NAME                0 (helloworld)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 POP_BLOCK           
             11 JUMP_FORWARD            14 (to 28)

  3     >>   14 POP_TOP             
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 POP_TOP             

  4          17 LOAD_NAME                1 (failure)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             23 POP_TOP             
             24 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 28)
             27 END_FINALLY         
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

Assuming that `helloworld()` raises an exception, the code follows from address 14 onwards. Because this except handler is generic, it makes sense that three POP_TOPs follow, and the `failure()` function call. However, afterwards, there is a `24 JUMP_FORWARD` which "jumps over" `27 END_FINALLY`, so that it doesn't get executed. What's its purpose here?

I noticed similar behaviour in versions 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8. In 3.9 it seems like it's renamed to RERAISE: https://godbolt.org/z/YbeqPf3nx

Some context: After simplifying an obfuscated pyc and a lot of debugging I've found that such structure breaks `uncompyle6`

Comment: Does the explanation from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#opcode-END_FINALLY) not answer this?

Comment: @zvone Sorry, I forgot to state that in the question. While I somewhat understand the description, what I don't understand is how does END_FINALLY ever get executed, if the execution jumps right before reaching that opcode

Comment: @musava_ribica It doesn't.  It's probably a left-over from compilation into bytecode.

Comment: I've edited the question to include versions 3.5-3.9 too. If it's there, there must also be a reason for that. See the last edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resumes propagation of an exception when a `finally` block ends, or when there is no `finally` block and none of the `except` blocks match. It also handles resuming a `return` or `continue` that was suspended by a `finally` block.

But you don't have a `finally`, and you've got a blanket `except`, which *always* matches, so the `END_FINALLY` never runs. It could be eliminated, but there's no handling in the bytecode compiler to do so.